# pointer is always byte aligned

Tags: c, pointers

I read something like pointer must be byte-aligned.
My understanding in  a typical 32bit architecture... all pointers are byte aligned...No ?

Please confirm.

can there be a pointer which is not byte-aligned ?

Basically this is mentioned in a hardware reference manual for tx descriptor memory.

Comment: no ... I m asking about  byte aligned only. I understand about word-aligned

Comment: Are you sure it's not "N byte aligned" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you cannot address any amount of memory smaller than a byte.

Answer (score 5):

In C, a pointer points to an object†

The only objects which are not a whole number of bytes are bit fields.

The C language does not allow you to create a pointer to a bit field; this code will result in a compiler error: "cannot take address of bit-field ‘b’":

```
struct S { unsigned int a:4, b:4, c:4, d:3, e:1; };

int main ( void ) {
    struct S s;
    int *i = &s.b; // would point half a byte into s
    return 0;
}
```

Pointers can only be incremented by a whole number of the size of object they point to.

Since you can't create such a pointer to an object of size less than one byte, or increment a pointer by less than one byte, you cannot have a pointer which is less than one byte aligned.

<sub>† in the C sense, not the OO sense</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If a pointer or a number is not byte aligned, it would start in the middle of a byte. I.e. some bits of a byte would belong to one pointer, and other bits to another. This would be strange and it does not occur in practice.

Comment: not 'does not occur' cannot occur because a byte is the smallest addressable unit...